# Doesn't gets frame from video in android 3.2.1 using MediaMetadataRetriever

Tags: android, video

I trying to get thumbnail from video using MediaMetadataRetriever class :

```
  MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        try {
            retriever.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/test.ts");

            Bitmap thumbnail = retriever.getFrameAtTime();
            ivThumbnail.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But all I get in my log:

```
E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI﹕ getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer
```

But the documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) says that this format supported in android 3.0+

For now this code works for .mp4 files. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This may help
get the video uri, and call this method..

```
public void setVideoThumbnail(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { BaseColumns._ID, MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BaseColumns._ID);
    int id = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);

    ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 1;
    Bitmap thumbnail= MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, id,
            MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
    ivThumbnail.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    ivThumbnail.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}
```

Comment: when getting cursor, cusror == null

Comment: My code:         File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/testts.ts");
        Log.e(TAG, "file.exists: " + file.exists());
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        setVideoThumbnail(uri);

Comment: uri file:///mnt/sdcard/testts.ts

Comment: try replacing Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null); by Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null); its working for me......

Comment: The same, but I found the warning for this method: "Method invocation 'getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'"

Comment: in what android version did you test this?

Comment: api Version 14 to 16;  instead of using the above method try using  android.media.ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(String filePath, int kind);

Comment: for this method I got: E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI﹕ getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer
 W/MediaMetadataRetriever﹕ MediaMetadataRetriever server died!

Comment: Android 3.2.1 motorola tablet

Answer (score 2):

Try to extract the frame of the video with [this external library](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever). It works on API 7 and doesn´t fails so many times than the MediaMetadataRetriever class. It should be very easy to add into your project...

Hope it´s useful

Comment: Thank you for answer! Today I will try it and then I will notify you.

Comment: I tried this library, but with no results. May be this library do not support .ts format

Comment: My code:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever(); mmr.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/testts.ts"); ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv)).setImageBitmap(mmr.getFrameAtTime());mmr.release();

Comment: Well... I didn´t know this, I´m sorry... I don´t know what could you do but one possibility is to use ffmpeg for android and convert the video file into a supported format... (This option will be a bit difficult). Good luck!!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try with convertor later.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

Check if you can extract meta data information from the video via `ExtractMetadata`. If not, there might be something wrong with the `setDataSource()` call or the video is in a wrong format/codec.

This code works for me.

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd=getAssets().openFd("t.mp4");
mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
```

I had to provide `afd.getStartOffset()` and `afd.getLength()`

Maybe it helps you get on the right track.